# Setting checkbox to checked with .prop not working

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to have all checkboxes (as list items) in an unordered list be checked once their parent checkbox is checked.

I've looked at a lot of Stackoverflow pages and tried many approaches that seem like they should work, but don't. I'm trying to figure out why one approach worked but 3 or 4 others didn't.

Worked:

```
$("#" + e + "areas").find("input[type='checkbox']").each(function () {
              this.checked = true;
             });
```

Did not work:

```
$("#" + e + "areas").find("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', this.checked);

$("#" + e + "areas").find("input[type='checkbox']").each(function () {
             $(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
          });
```

This is the function in which it exists and currently works:

```
function toggleAreas(e) {
      if (!$("#" + e + "areas").is(':visible')) {
          $("#" + e + "areas").css({ 'display': '', 'list-style-type': 'none' });
          $("#" + e + "areas").find("input[type='checkbox']").each(function () {
              this.checked = true;
             });
      }
      else {
         $("#" + e + "areas").css({ 'display': 'none' });
      }
    }
```

HTML:

```
<ul style="list-style-type:none;">
    <li style="list-style-type:none;">
    <input type="checkbox" value="Central" id="5dept" name="5" onclick="toggleAreas(&quot;5&quot;)">
    <label for="Central">Central</label>
        <ul id="5areas" style="list-style-type: none;">
            <li><input type="checkbox" value="Administration" id="41area" name="Administration">
                <label for="Administration">Administration</label>
            </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" value="Contact Center" id="39area" name="Contact Center">
                <label for="Contact Center">Contact Center</label>
            </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" value="Intake" id="38area" name="Intake">
                <label for="Intake">Intake</label>
            </li>
        </ul
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually when you typing `$("#" + e + "areas").find("input[type='checkbox']")` this selector returning the collection of DOM elements so there should not `this` applicable. So apply this way you should `$("#" + e + "areas").find("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', true/false);`.

But when you typing:

```
$("#" + e + "areas").find("input[type='checkbox']").each(function () {
    this.checked = true;
});
```

That means `each` function iterating on each item of DOM element so why we getting `this` here.

Comment: I tried the way you suggested and that worked. I guess I am confused about 'this'. I thought 'this' would refer to each item as it's being iterated over.

Answer (score 0):

The code below didn't work because `this.checked` outside the loop is undefined.

```
  $("#" + e + "areas").find("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', this.checked);
```

This works:

```
  $("#" + e + "areas").find("input[type='checkbox']").each(function () {
                 $(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
   });
```

The `this` variable is existing in the loop because `each()` set every loop `this` to an element from the array that you got when doing `$("#" + e + "areas").find("input[type='checkbox']")`

Comment: I'm not sure how the one that worked has 'this' as defined but the others don't.